# Query inside reducer ? redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

How do i write this inside of an reducer to change the state?

```
doc = {
  id:"zf123ada123ad",
  name:"examp",
  subdoc:{
    name:"subdoc examp",
    subsubdoc:[{
               id:"zcgsdf123zaar21",
               subsubsubdoc:[{
                             id:"af2317bh123",
                             value: "heyhey"   //this value I want to update
                            }]
              }]
}
}
```

let's say i have an reducer that looks like this
The action.payload look something like this
{
theInputId1: "someId",
theInputId2: "anotherId",
theInputValue: "someValue"
}

```
export function updateSubSubSubDoc(state = {}, action){
  switch(action.type){
    case 'UPDATE_THE_SUBSUBSUB':
      return {
               state.doc.subdoc.subsubdoc.find(x => x.id == 
          theInputId1).subsubsubdoc.find(x => x.id == theInputId2).value = theInputValue  // just example code for you to understand where i'm going.
             }

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

What I want to do it update one subsubsub doc in a state that is current

Comment: It is not clear how you represent the state. Initially it was `false` and suddenly it became something that has `doc.subdoc.subsubdoc` that even has `where` method.

Comment: That is a typo from me when copying

Comment: I updated it, the where method, is not implemented. But it's suppose to be a query to find and object by id inside an array of objects

Comment: Did you mean `find`? [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: yeah i guess so, it's not ment to be working but only to explain what i want to do

Comment: Your return statement does WAY too much in a single line of code. Break it into multiple lines so you can more easily reason about the steps.

Comment: This is a good example of why your state should not be deeply nested.

Comment: immutable.js may be worth looking into: https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ES6, this is one way that you could do that:

```
const initialState = { doc: { subdoc: { subsubdoc: {} } } };
export function doc(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'UPDATE_THE_SUBSUBSUB':
      const subsubdocIdx = state.doc.subdoc.
        subsubdoc.find(s => s.id == action.theInputId1);
      const subsubdoc = state.doc.subdoc.subsubdoc[subsubdocIdx];
      const subsubsubdocIdx = state.doc.subdoc.
        subsubdoc[subsubdocIdx].
        subsubsubdoc.find(s => s.id == action.theInputId2);
      const subsubsubdoc = state.doc.subdoc.
        subsubdoc[subsubdocIdx].
        subsubsubdoc[subsubsubdocIdx];
      return {
        ...state,
        doc: {
          ...state.doc,
          subdoc: {
            ...state.doc.subdoc,
            subsubdoc: [
              ...state.doc.subdoc.subsubdoc.slice(0, subsubdocIdx),
              {
                ...subsubdoc,
                subsubsubdoc: [
                  ...subsubdoc.slice(0, subsubsubdocIdx),
                  {
                    ...subsubsubdoc,
                    value: action.theInputValue,
                  },
                  ...subsubdoc.subsubsubdoc.slice(subsubsubdocIdx + 1, subsubdoc.subsubsubdoc.length - 1),
                ],
              },
              ...state.doc.subdoc.subsubdoc.slice(subsubdocIdx + 1, state.doc.subdoc.subsubdoc.length - 1),
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

(I haven’t tested this code.)

This is nested the same level as in your example, but you might consider using something like `combineReducers` to make this a little easier to manage. This is also presupposing you have other actions that create the document chain along the way, and you know these documents exist.

Here's an example how you might be able to do it with `combineReducers`:

```
function doc(state = {}, action) {
}

function subdoc(state = {}, action) {
}

function subsubdoc(state = [], action) {
}

function subsubsubdoc(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'UPDATE_THE_SUBSUBSUB':
      const idx = state.find(s => s.id == action.theInputId2);
      return [
        ...state.slice(0, idx),
        {
          ...state[idx],
          value: action.theInputValue,
        },
        ...state.slice(idx + 1),
      ];
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default combineReducers({
  doc,
  subdoc,
  subsubdoc,
  subsubsubdoc,
});
```

In this example, you don't need `action.theInputId1`, but you would need to store some reference in the data from the subsubdoc to the subsubsubdoc so that when you're rendering, you can piece it back together. Same with all of the other layers.

Comment: This much nesting suggests that it needs to be refactored.

Comment: 100% agreed. I'd use `combineReducers` in my own code to break it into smaller reducers.

Comment: How would that look like?

Comment: Added an edit that shows an example of how to do it using a shallower structure using `combineReducers`.

Comment: Thank you very much @EricLevine !